# calculate median group by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as such where there are different plan id's and each plan id also has different route_ids.

```
   plan_id route_id   dtn
   801      12289     2629.0
   801      12289     1666.0
   801      12289     0.0
   801      12289     2216.0
   801      7734      2219.0
   801      7734      853.0
   653      8819      3375.0
   653      8819      2184.0
.
.
.
.
```

dtn is in seconds. and **dtn is the distance to next delivery in the route, i.e., at index 3 that would be the distance between delivery index 3 and delivery index 4.****

I need to find the median of dtn for each route_id per given plan_id and append it as a column to the existing dataframe matched to the corresponding pid and route_id. how can I do this?

Comment: Why exactly would you want to append this data as new rows within the existing DataFrame? Seems to me that you would probably be better storing this aggregate data in another DataFrame or structure as to maintain the integrity of the original and not confuse it.

Comment: I would like to append it as a new column like 'median _ dtn'

Comment: You state in your original question that you want both median `dtn` by `route_id` and median `dtn` by `plan_id`.

Comment: yes, I want the dtn median grouped by  route_id and plan_id, since plans have multiple route_id's.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') # Load dummy data (from original question example)

# Get median vals grouped by relevant cols
r_med = df.groupby('route_id')[['dtn']].median()
p_med = df.groupby('plan_id')[['dtn']].median()

# Append both relevant median vals as cols to each row
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i, 'median_route_dtn'] = r_med.loc[row['route_id'], 'dtn']
    df.loc[i, 'median_plan_dtn'] = p_med.loc[row['plan_id'], 'dtn']
```

Gives the following `df`:

```
   plan_id  route_id     dtn  median_route_dtn  median_plan_dtn
0      801     12289  2629.0            1941.0           1941.0
1      801     12289  1666.0            1941.0           1941.0
2      801     12289     0.0            1941.0           1941.0
3      801     12289  2216.0            1941.0           1941.0
4      801      7734  2219.0            1536.0           1941.0
5      801      7734   853.0            1536.0           1941.0
6      653      8819  3375.0            2779.5           2779.5
7      653      8819  2184.0            2779.5           2779.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Median for each route_id:

```
    df.groupby('route_id')[['dtn']].median()
```

Median for each plan_id:

```
 df.groupby('plan_id')[['dtn']].median()
```

Comment: "dtn is the distance to next delivery in the route, i.e., at index 3 that would be the distance between delivery index 3 and delivery index 4". Does this information not affect the group by procedure?